# How to commit fine change and keep log simple using git

Tags: git

When I develop an new feature, I may tune my code many times for a better performance. In the 100 test times, I may got better performance at time 1, time 13, time 43, ...

Should I commit the code when got a better performance?

If so, I will get lots of small commit logs in my history if there are some small changes (eg. typo, or just make the code be more beautiful). But most time I can not do it at once, it usually takes me many and many times.

What's the better way to log above small changes?

Comment: I advocate a large number of small commits. Just make sure that each one is a logical entity and the messages are good.

Answer (score 3):

In case you what to reduce an mount of commits and simultaneously keep a detailed history I would recommend to use feature branch + the squash method. Here is an example:

Suppose you are on the `master` branch with no local changes.

First create a feature branch

```
$ git checkout -b tuning
```

Then perform your tuning commiting each relevant step

```
... small change ...
$ git commit -am "Time 1"

... small change ...
$ git commit -am "Time 2"

... small change ...
$ git commit -am "Time 3"

...
```

Now the history looks like this

```
* (tuning) Time 3
|
* Time 2
|
* Time 1
|
* (master)
```

Next create a temporary branch and squash all changes to a single commit on `master` branch. This is done by reseting to the original master branch preserving local content and git index (`--soft`), then checking out `master` branch and then commiting into it.

```
git checkout -b tmp
git reset --soft master
git checkout master
git commit -m "Tuned (see tuning branch for more details)"
git branch -D tmp
```

Now you get a single commit on the `master` branch and a whole history of this commit on the `tuning` branch.

```
* (master) Tuned (see tuning branch for more details)
|
| * (tuning) Time 3
| |
| * Time 2
| |
| * Time 1
| /
*
|
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer having a large number of small feature related commits, in this way you can easily revert a commit to go back to a previous state.

When you're working with other developers you've to consider company policies when `pushing` on a central repository.

When working on your local copy, `git` gives you the tools to merge your commits using `rebase`:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

Will open an interactive rebase on the last 5 commits, you can then choose the `squash` or `fixup` option to merge them together:

```
 #  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
 #  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
```

In this way you can then `push` just a single commit to the central repo.